# How to access property of union type object without type casting in Typescript

Tags: typescript

I have the following types:

```
export type a = {
  todo: string;
};

export type b = {
  id: number;
};

export type TodosAction = Action<string> & (a | b);
```

and I have a function:

```
function doSmth(action:TodosAction){
  switch(action.type){
    case "a":
      action.todo //TS error, doesn't exist
      (action as a).todo // Works fine this way
  }
}
```

How can I access/get `todo` property without typecasting with `as`?

**Edit:**

```
type Action<T>={
  type:T;
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Did you define the `type` property somewhere? Are you looking for [type guards](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to declare `type` property in every interface of union type:

```js
export type a = {
  type: 'a';
  todo: string;
};

export type b = {
  type: 'b';
  id: number;
};
```

Typescript's feature you're trying to use is called Discriminated Union, and it require some literal string (or number) as type of some property declared in every type that is part of union.
In your case it would be `type` property with values 'a' or 'b'. Then you can check this property in you function:

```js
function doSmth(action:TodosAction){
  switch(action.type){
    case "a":
      action.todo; // no error - action is type of 'a' object
      break;
    case "b":
      action.id; // also no error - action is type of 'b' object
      break;
  }
}
```

Note you need to remember about `break` keyword to make it work.

Comment: could you please check my Edit, sorry forgot to include type `Action` which has `type` key

Comment: @MartinSergio, unfortunately type Action will not work in way you meant it would. If you want to preserve Action type, you could exchange types a and b to interfaces extending Action, but I'd suggest you to get rid of this Action type. IMO it's useless. My solution you can find above will work without Action type.